# What does scalar mean in perl?

Tags: perl, terminology

In perl, you have three main [data types](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata), "scalars, arrays of scalars, and associative arrays of scalars". What exactly is perl trying to convey with the name "scalar"? What's the metaphor, the mental image that should be forming?

I can infer an analogy: single value, a list of values, a list of named values. But this doesn't help me understand why the word "scalar" is used. Perl's scalars surely do not [resemble a ladder](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=scalar).

Comment: I see it as scalar vs vector (of math/physics/etc), as single value vs multiple values, loosely.  but I don't know what they actually had in mind when they named it that :)

Comment: Explanation: [Perl - scalars](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_scalars.htm)

Comment: From [wikipedia: Scalar (physics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_(physics)): *"In physics, a scalar or scalar quantity is a quantity that can be described by a __single element__ of a number field, such as a real number, ... __in contrast to vectors__, tensors, etc. which are described by __several numbers__ ...*" And it is similar with the use of "scalar" in math.

Comment: I am seeing this more and more in computing today.

Many mathematical terms in common use today – including scalar and vector – were introduced by William Rowan Hamilton, circa 1846, as he developed the theory of quaternions. https://physicsworld.com/a/william-rowan-hamilton-mathematical-genius/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This concept is described in principle in [Variable (Computer Science)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_(computer_science)) wherein it says:

> In computer programming, a variable or scalar is a storage location
> (identified by a memory address) paired with an associated symbolic
> name, which contains some known or unknown quantity of information
> referred to as a value. The variable name is the usual way to
> reference the stored value, in addition to referring to the variable
> itself, depending on the context.

In Perl, a scalar variable holds a single value. While a Perl scalar is typically associated with a symbolic name, it doesn't have to be; you can have a scalar that is only referred to by a scalar reference, and not paired with a symbol. The usage of the word "scalar" in computer programming probably derives from a similar usage in mathematics, as described in [Scalar (Mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_(mathematics)):

> A scalar is an element of a field which is used to define a vector
> space. A quantity described by multiple scalars, such as having both
> direction and magnitude, is called a vector.

As applied to Perl, scalars are described in [perldoc perldata](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata):

> A scalar may contain one single value in any of three different
> flavors: a number, a string, or a reference. In general, conversion
> from one form to another is transparent. Although a scalar may not
> directly hold multiple values, it may contain a reference to an array
> or hash which in turn contains multiple values.

Perl scalars, internally, store a few things; an IV (integer value), an NV (floating point numeric value), PV (pointer to string value), SV (a reference), a reference count, some various flags to keep track of if the scalar has Unicode semantics, other "magic", and which of the various storage types are in use. Not all of these buckets are in use at any given time, and which ones are populated depends both on how the scalar is defined, and on how it is used (a scalar holding a string may later populate the IV or NV fields, internally, if it is treated as a number). This is described in [perlguts](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts#Datatypes), but you usually don't need to worry about it.

You can informally consider a scalar to be a single unit of storage which may contain a number, a string, or a reference. And you may consider a scalar to be either a standalone variable, a unit of storage referred to by a scalar reference, or a single element of an array or hash.

Comment: A scalar is a single value. It does not need to be associated with a name.

Comment: @briandfoy I already mentioned that it doesn't need to be associated with a name. Is there something I should edit to better capture your comment's intent? Happy to make an update. I read the OP's question pretty carefully, and he already seemed to have been aware of perldata, which would have explained a scalar is a single value.

Comment: Start with the main message you want someone to remember and correct from there, but only if you have to. You have a heck of a lot of text here for what should be a really simple answer.

Comment: This adjacent answer about what it means that programming languages appropriated the word "vector" from maths is also helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/508440/659715 In a sense, the first answer to my question is "because arrays are vectors, and vectors are composed of scalars". It begs yet many more questions itself, but is elucidating..

Answer (score 2):

A scalar is a single distinct value, like 47 or "Bob Smith".  Scalar variables use the `$` sigil.

```
my $score = 47;
my $name = "Bob Smith";
```

An array is an ordered list of 0 or more scalars, indexable by a nonnegative integer.  Array variables use the `@` sigil.

```
my @scores = ( 47, 52, 34 );
my @names = ( "Bob Smith", "Susan Richardson", "Heather Jones" );

my $first_score = $scores[0];  # 47
my $last_score = $scores[-1];  # 34, indexed from the end
```

A hash or associative array is an unordered list of strings that map to scalars.  Hash variables use the `%` sigil.

```
my %scores = (
    "Bob Smith" => 47,
    "Susan Richardson" => 52,
    "Heather Jones" => 34,
);

my $score_for_susan = $scores{"Susan Richardson"};   # Has the value 52
my $score_for_doug = $scores{"Doug Thompson"};   # Has the value undef 
# because the key "Doug Thompson" does not exist in %scores.
```

It can be confusing that a hash like `%scores` is expressed as `$scores` when looking up a value.

Comment: Good point, I've edited all three mentions to say variables. thanks.

Comment: This explains what a scalar _is_ in perl, but not what it _means_. The word scalar is much older than perl. I'm apt to presume Larry Wall picked the word scalar because something about its non-perl meaning relates to what perl scalars are.

Answer (score 0):

how about string "data" or number "data", a variable representing "data".

Comment: But why the word scalar? Long before Larry Wall's parents were conceived, the word existed. To Larry, was "scalar" merely a pleasing assortment of letters? Or does perl's use of the word relate to extant (or even extinct!) meaning?